# Сравнение двух файлов конфигурации

Tags: python

У меня есть два файла конфигурации (дефолтная и юзер-конфигурация), которые содержат строчки `значение = параметр`. Мне нужно сравнить эти два файла, чтобы в обоих файлах обязательно присутствовали и были равны строчки `значение`, а параметр может быть любой.

Пока я могу сравнить только 2 файла на наличие вообще какой-то разницы, но пока к сожалению не построчно, помогите в этом разобраться:

```
def compareConfigs():
    file1 = open('default_config.ini', 'r')
    file2 = open('user_config.ini', 'r')
    if file1 == file2:
        print("Конфигурации равны")
    else:
        print("Конфигурации не равны.")

compareConfigs()
```

Comment: Я пробовал реализовать это через массив, с построчным сравнением, как в этом примере: http://www.cyberforum.ru/python-beginners/thread2481505.html это уже лучше, осталось разбить строчки, и только "первые кусочки" сравнивать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
def compareConfigs(): 
    file1 = open('default_config.ini', 'r')
    file2 = open('user_config.ini', 'r')
    s1=[line.split('=')[0] for line in file1]
    s2=[line.split('=')[0] for line in file2]
    file1.close()
    file2.close()
    for line1 in s1:
        if line1 not in s2:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: да, супер, но пайтон ругается на `;` в строчке `file1.close(); file2.close()` пишет PEP 8: multiple statements on one line (semicolon)

Comment: @Igor-Potapov поправил код

Comment: Спасибо! вы лучший!

Comment: Подскажите, можно ли разбивать строчку на три части, двумя разделителями? Например `параметр 1 = значение 1`  а на следующей строчке может быть такое `значение 2 : True` чтобы я получал успех при изменении текста, который находится и за знаком "=" и за знаком двоеточие ":". Я пробую реализовать через `for` `in` и добавляю `and` с записью в массив [1] данных после двоеточия...

Comment: Я постепил так: я используя `[line.replace(' :', '=')[0] for line in file1]` заменил все двоеточия на =, и теперь у меня уже в каждой строчке будут знаки =, кроме одной, там было так: `параметр 1 = значение 1 : True` по этому после выполнения моей функции будет следубщее: `параметр 1 = значение 1 = True`